# Convert ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> "back" to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an ArrayList consisting of several ArrayLists, all containing String elements.

That is;

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> myListCollection = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Now, is there a way to convert **myListCollection** to an ArrayList containing only String elements?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I have written several methods that for adding Strings to a list. Each list is then added to a "superlist", of the type:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
```

Seeing as this now is a collection of lists, which in turn contain single String elements, I was wondering if it would be possible to change my "superlist" into a list containing all the String elements, as opposed to a list containing other list elements with String elements.

For instance, retrieving an element from the "superlist" gives me an entire list, whereas I would like access to single elements.

I think I can use a nested for-loop to retrieve an element within a sublist, with the following code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < superlist.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < superlist.get(i).size(); j++) {
            System.out.println(superlist.get(i).get(j));
        }
    }
```

Is this proper/correct/decent code?

Comment: Yes.  Please show any code attempt you have so far, along with any problems you've encountered; a solution won't just be given here.

Comment: Do you mean just by flattening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, something like that:

```
ArrayList<String> stringCollection = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < myListCollection.size(); ++i) {
 stringCollection.addAll(myListCollection.get(i));
}
```

hope it works for you :).

Comment: It did indeed help me! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Note that you usually want to use a definiton `List<String> coll = new ArrayList<String>()` or even better `Collection<String> coll`. This will allow you to change implementation easily if, say, you only want distinct strings (you can then set `coll = new HashSet<String>()` and you're done